# Deleted post status: "2 more votes are needed to undelete this post"

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974523/how-can-i-write-c-main-function/29974595#29974595) to a question related to the `main` method. Though the answer was technically correct, it could have a negative impact on young developers, so I deleted it. Due to the fact that someone flagged my answer for deletion, my answer now has the odd status of waiting for two more votes to get undeleted, which is incorrect as only I can undelete it (and maybe some high-ranked moderators).

Here's a screenshot of my deleted post:

[image]

**Edit:** Thank you all for the clarification. I was under the impression that the close flag (as the answer had one before I deleted) was incorrectly converted to an "undelete" flag, which was not the case.

Comment: I think only 10k+ users can see deleted questions/answers

Comment: I had edited and voted to undelete your post, since I think you had made a valid point with your answer. You deleted prematurely, and may simply decide to accept my edits (add your own flavor additionally), and undelete your answer, as I've suggested. (Which would enable me to upvote it BTW).

Comment: @TimCastelijns: One can always see ones own questions, as well as ones own answers on non-deleted questions.

Comment: Wow... didn't know that posts that I deleted can be undeleted by community

Comment: @Cristik if one of your posts is considered valuable by the community (e.g. it has lots op upvotes) we would rather not see it deleted, even if you would want it so. Hence the option to undelete

Comment: Though iff you really want, you can ask for dissassociation from your post with an other-flag. Should be seldom enough that a post should not be deleted but you really don't want to be known as the author.

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification, I have undeleted my post meanwhile. I was under the impression that the close flag (as the answer had one before I deleted) was incorrectly converted to an "undelete" flag.

Comment: The disassociation does require mod intervention though, so use sparingly.

Comment: I don't think I'll use this feature, I assume all mistakes I make, so unless my post has a negative impact on young minds, or is completely wrong, I will leave it there, regardless of how many downvotes it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Due to the fact that someone flagged my answer for deletion, my answer now has the odd status of waiting for two more votes to get undeleted, which is incorrect as only I can undelete it (and maybe some high-ranked moderators)."*

I was *"someone"* actually.

Your answer was probably downvoted for some slightly unfortunate wording, and I've edited it to be more precise about the preconditions (the question already is tagged [visual-studio2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio2010)), and voted to undelete, since your answer basically solves the problem stated in the OP.

You may simply decide to agree with me, and accept my improvements and undelete your answer, or wait for two more undelete votes being applied by any other users with enough rep to cast these.